# is there a way to show for XCode's intellisense to show only class and instance methods?

Tags: objective-c, xcode, xcode4, xcode4.2

Is there a way to show for XCode's intellisense to show only class and instance methods? Not the inherited ones.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As of XCode 4 - answer is can't be done.